# MySQL Workbench cant open on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

i have installed MySQL-Server on Cent OS 7 but workbench denied to open. More specifically when i try to open workbench on the bottom bar i see for a moment that is trying to open but it crashes an never opened without seeing any failed message. MySQL from command prompt works flawless, also i am able to start and stop daemon without any issues. I have already tried mysqladmin -u root -p version didn't saw any issues. Also i tried to re install only workbench but did not work, after i uninstalled everything and reinstalled them but didn't work. I tried older packages but didn't work as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you read this guide? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html

Comment: I have read the guide and tried all these but didn't help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Which version of centOS you use?

Comment: I use CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

Comment: I have same problem as you do, CentOS cannot open MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Hello, downgrade your version to that one:  "mysql-workbench-community-6.2.5-1.el7.x86_64.rpm" and it will be worked. If you still want to use version 6.3.10 be sure that package gtkmm30 is updated to version  3.22 but not sure if that works, for me didnt.

Comment: When you have issues like this, open a command line terminal window and start the application from this terminal, if there's something wrong, you will often see error messages printed out to the terminal - error messages that could be informative - but usually lost if you start the application from some desktop icon or menu.

Comment: Last version of MySQL workbench works like a charm at CentOS 7.4.

Answer (score 0):

Last version is not working on centos 7;

you can downgrade mysql-workbench.

Install the mysql repository from the mysql website. Then enter:

```
yum remove mysql-workbench
yum install yum-plugin-versionlock
yum install mysql-workbench-community-6.3.8-1.el7.*
yum versionlock mysql-workbench-community-6.3.8-1.el7.*
```

https://teonotebook.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/latest-mysql-workbench-crashes-on-centos-7-downgrade-to-a-previous-version/

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the latest version of MySQL-workbench on Centos 7.
See the detailed guide here.
The same install can probably work on other **similar** Linux distro with simple modifications.

https://superuser.com/questions/785814/installing-mysql-workbench-on-centos/1511574#1511574

Comment: Have already being resolved! Therefore, thank you for sharing the link. Cheers.